# Unable to open direct websocket connection (without stomp) to amazonmq

Tags: websocket, amazon-mq

I'm trying to connect to the WebSocket endpoint on AmazonMQ (ActiveMQ) from a webpage (hosted on HTTPS).

```
let wsURL = "wss://url_to_mq:61619";
let wssConn = new WebSocket(wsURL);
```

This reports a failure to connect to the WebSocket.

On AmazonMQ, I defined port 61619 to be open to all IPs in the security group.

How can I utilize the wss endpoint from the AmazonMQ dashboard to directly connect from my website to ActiveMQ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further exploration, it appears that only stomp fully negotiates (and authenticates) the connection of a Websocket from a js-based frontend to an Amazonmq (ActiveMQ) backend.  The WSS endpoints are passed directly to the stomp client in the following manner given that stomp.js is added to the page:

```
    var client = Stomp.client(WS_URL);
    let login = "username";
    let passcode = "password";

    function connectCallback() {
        console.log("Connected.");

    }

    function errorCallback(error) {
        console.log(error, "Error Connecting.");
    }

    function closeEventCallback () {
        console.log("Closed.");
    }

    client.connect(login, passcode, connectCallback, errorCallback, 
        closeEventCallback);
```

I hope this helps the next individual seeking this solution and may be confused as to why the WSS endpoints do not directly work with a direct WebSocket instantiation.